# Custom image model not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have got a custom model for my images that should be able to locate the correct folder. And then let me resize images by doing this in model. example `$this->model_tool_image->resize($this->settings->get('config_image'), 100, 100);`

I know codeigniter has one but not what I am after.

For some reason not picking up images even though they are there. I think it may be a problem with the directories? All images are kept in `base_url() . 'images/catalog'` The posted image name can be got from DB fine.

**Error: Could not load image !** Very strange I have defined path on model and it is working.

No images display

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Model_tool_image extends CI_Model {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('images');
        define('DIR_IMAGE', base_url('image/catalog') .'/');
    }

    public function resize($filename, $width, $height) {


        if (!is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $filename)) {
            return;
        }

        $extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        $old_image = $filename;

        $new_image = DIR_IMAGE . utf8_substr($filename, 0, utf8_strrpos($filename, '.')) . '-' . $width . 'x' . $height . '.' . $extension;

        if (!is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $new_image) || (filectime(DIR_IMAGE . $old_image) > filectime(DIR_IMAGE . $new_image))) {

            $path = '';

            $directories = explode('/', dirname(str_replace('../', '', $new_image)));


            foreach ($directories as $directory) {
                $path = $path . '/' . $directory;

                if (!is_dir(DIR_IMAGE . $path)) {
                    @mkdir(DIR_IMAGE . $path, 0777);
                }
            }

            list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize(DIR_IMAGE . $old_image);

            if ($width_orig != $width || $height_orig != $height) {
                $image = new Image(DIR_IMAGE . $old_image);
                $image->resize($width, $height);
                $image->save(DIR_IMAGE . $new_image);
            } else {
                copy(DIR_IMAGE . $old_image, DIR_IMAGE . $new_image);
            }
        }

        if ($this->input->server('HTTPS')) {
            return HTTPS_SERVER . 'image/catalog/' . $new_image;
        } else {
            return HTTP_SERVER . 'image/catalog/' . $new_image;
        }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
$this->load->library('settings'); // Gets image from db OK example; nemo.png
$this->load->model('admin/tool/model_tool_image');

echo DIR_IMAGE;

if (!empty($this->input->post('config_image')) ) {
    $data['config_image'] = $this->input->post('config_image');
} else {
    $data['config_image'] =  $this->settings->get('config_image');
}

if (!empty($this->input->post('config_image')) && is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $this->input->post('config_image'))) {
$data['thumb'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize($this->input->post('config_image'), 100, 100);
} elseif ($this->settings->get('config_image') && is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $this->settings->get('config_image'))) {
$data['thumb'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize($this->settings->get('config_image'), 100, 100);
} else {
$data['thumb'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize(base_url() . 'image/no_image.png', 100, 100);
    }

$data['placeholder'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize(base_url() . 'image/no_image.png', 100, 100);

return $this->load->view('setting/settings', $data);
```

Custom Images Library

```
<?php

class Images {
    private $file;
    private $image;
    private $info;

    public function __construct($file = '') {
        if (file_exists($file)) {
            $this->file = $file;

            $info = getimagesize($file);

            $this->info = array(
                'width'  => $info[0],
                'height' => $info[1],
                'bits'   => isset($info['bits']) ? $info['bits'] : '',
                'mime'   => isset($info['mime']) ? $info['mime'] : ''
            );

            $this->image = $this->create($file);
        } else {
            exit('Error: Could not load image ' . $file . '!');
        }
    }

    private function create($image) {
        $mime = $this->info['mime'];

        if ($mime == 'image/gif') {
            return imagecreatefromgif ($image);
        } elseif ($mime == 'image/png') {
            return imagecreatefrompng($image);
        } elseif ($mime == 'image/jpeg') {
            return imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
        }
    }

    public function save($file, $quality = 90) {
        $info = pathinfo($file);

        $extension = strtolower($info['extension']);

        if (is_resource($this->image)) {
            if ($extension == 'jpeg' || $extension == 'jpg') {
                imagejpeg($this->image, $file, $quality);
            } elseif ($extension == 'png') {
                imagepng($this->image, $file);
            } elseif ($extension == 'gif') {
                imagegif ($this->image, $file);
            }

            imagedestroy($this->image);
        }
    }

    public function resize($width = 0, $height = 0, $default = '') {
        if (!$this->info['width'] || !$this->info['height']) {
            return;
        }

        $xpos = 0;
        $ypos = 0;
        $scale = 1;

        $scale_w = $width / $this->info['width'];
        $scale_h = $height / $this->info['height'];

        if ($default == 'w') {
            $scale = $scale_w;
        } elseif ($default == 'h') {
            $scale = $scale_h;
        } else {
            $scale = min($scale_w, $scale_h);
        }

        if ($scale == 1 && $scale_h == $scale_w && $this->info['mime'] != 'image/png') {
            return;
        }

        $new_width = (int)($this->info['width'] * $scale);
        $new_height = (int)($this->info['height'] * $scale);
        $xpos = (int)(($width - $new_width) / 2);
        $ypos = (int)(($height - $new_height) / 2);

        $image_old = $this->image;
        $this->image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

        if (isset($this->info['mime']) && $this->info['mime'] == 'image/png') {
            imagealphablending($this->image, false);
            imagesavealpha($this->image, true);
            $background = imagecolorallocatealpha($this->image, 255, 255, 255, 127);
            imagecolortransparent($this->image, $background);
        } else {
            $background = imagecolorallocate($this->image, 255, 255, 255);
        }

        imagefilledrectangle($this->image, 0, 0, $width, $height, $background);

        imagecopyresampled($this->image, $image_old, $xpos, $ypos, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $this->info['width'], $this->info['height']);
        imagedestroy($image_old);

        $this->info['width']  = $width;
        $this->info['height'] = $height;
    }

    public function watermark($file, $position = 'bottomright') {
        $watermark = $this->create($file);

        $watermark_width = imagesx($watermark);
        $watermark_height = imagesy($watermark);

        switch($position) {
            case 'topleft':
                $watermark_pos_x = 0;
                $watermark_pos_y = 0;
                break;
            case 'topright':
                $watermark_pos_x = $this->info['width'] - $watermark_width;
                $watermark_pos_y = 0;
                break;
            case 'bottomleft':
                $watermark_pos_x = 0;
                $watermark_pos_y = $this->info['height'] - $watermark_height;
                break;
            case 'bottomright':
                $watermark_pos_x = $this->info['width'] - $watermark_width;
                $watermark_pos_y = $this->info['height'] - $watermark_height;
                break;
        }

        imagecopy($this->image, $watermark, $watermark_pos_x, $watermark_pos_y, 0, 0, 120, 40);

        imagedestroy($watermark);
    }

    public function crop($top_x, $top_y, $bottom_x, $bottom_y) {
        $image_old = $this->image;
        $this->image = imagecreatetruecolor($bottom_x - $top_x, $bottom_y - $top_y);

        imagecopy($this->image, $image_old, 0, 0, $top_x, $top_y, $this->info['width'], $this->info['height']);
        imagedestroy($image_old);

        $this->info['width'] = $bottom_x - $top_x;
        $this->info['height'] = $bottom_y - $top_y;
    }

    public function rotate($degree, $color = 'FFFFFF') {
        $rgb = $this->html2rgb($color);

        $this->image = imagerotate($this->image, $degree, imagecolorallocate($this->image, $rgb[0], $rgb[1], $rgb[2]));

        $this->info['width'] = imagesx($this->image);
        $this->info['height'] = imagesy($this->image);
    }

    private function filter($filter) {
        imagefilter($this->image, $filter);
    }

    private function text($text, $x = 0, $y = 0, $size = 5, $color = '000000') {
        $rgb = $this->html2rgb($color);

        imagestring($this->image, $size, $x, $y, $text, imagecolorallocate($this->image, $rgb[0], $rgb[1], $rgb[2]));
    }

    private function merge($file, $x = 0, $y = 0, $opacity = 100) {
        $merge = $this->create($file);

        $merge_width = imagesx($merge);
        $merge_height = imagesy($merge);

        imagecopymerge($this->image, $merge, $x, $y, 0, 0, $merge_width, $merge_height, $opacity);
    }

    private function html2rgb($color) {
        if ($color[0] == '#') {
            $color = substr($color, 1);
        }

        if (strlen($color) == 6) {
            list($r, $g, $b) = array($color[0] . $color[1], $color[2] . $color[3], $color[4] . $color[5]);
        } elseif (strlen($color) == 3) {
            list($r, $g, $b) = array($color[0] . $color[0], $color[1] . $color[1], $color[2] . $color[2]);
        } else {
            return false;
        }

        $r = hexdec($r);
        $g = hexdec($g);
        $b = hexdec($b);

        return array($r, $g, $b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check to make sure that you are passing a value to the `Image` library.

Comment: I put it on the user model parent and that's when it shows error.

Comment: If you look at the Library code in your question, it will echo the value of your image, i.e. the name of the file, along with that error(in the `public function __construct($file = '')`). in other words, `image/no_image.png` is not being sent to your method.

What is `echo DIR_IMAGE;` returning?

Comment: echo DIR_IMAGE is returning path set on model. In controller for testing

Comment: are you trying to resize the image to different dimensions...?

Comment: By the model and then in controller like above. As said I have tried codeigniter way And it not what I am after.

Comment: What happens if you `var_dump($file)` inside your Image constructor? You should receive a file path that you can put into your browser and see the image show up. If you cannot do that you could have 1) file permission issues or 2) a bad path to the file.  Make sure the letter casing on the filename and directory definitions are exactly what you find in your file system

Answer (score 0):

define your DIR_IMAGE like this way at your model

```
define('DIR_IMAGE', FCPATH.'image/catalog/');
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you schould use define like that. if you use a constant in a class you schould define it like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    const MYCONSTANT = 'constant value';

    function showConstant() {
        echo  self::MYCONSTANT. "\n";
    }
}
```

Also i would recomand if you use a namespace capable php version to take a look at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php 
it is namespace defined, and also i am not sure if define works inside a class... tht is usualy in procedural code.